# Json Code Validation Error Curl Post Request

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl, netbeans

I am getting following JSON output using curl in PHP

CURL:

```
$request = curl_init("{$config['root']}/api/tickets");
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    add_headers($request);    
    $response = curl_exec($request);
```

Function:

```
function add_headers($request) {
    global $config;
    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
    if (empty($config['accessClient'])) {
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$config['user']}:{$config['password']}");
    } else {
        array_push($headers, "Access-Client-Token: {$config['accessClient']}");
    }
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}
```

Output:

```
"{"amount":"100","description":"A ticket of 100.","payer":null,"successUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/ticket-confirmed.php","successWebhook":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/ticket-confirmed-webhook.php","cancelUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/shop","orderId":"OID-1","expiresAfter":{"amount":1,"field":"hours"},"customValues":{}}"
```

and curl response is "

> `"{"Code":"Validation"}"`

Developer Console:

> Malformed JSON Ouput

*Note: Values got from NetBeans Variables.
When I check output from Json validator it gets invalid only because of double quotes in start and end of output that I think is not bad in php when we assign a json output into variable.*

Test Cyclos API [here](https://demo.cyclos.org/api#!/Tickets/newTicket). ***U***: demo **P**: 1234

Comment: it is 3rd part API?

Comment: @Vel yes its cyclos

Comment: @Vel can you help me

Comment: Hi, I dont have account in cyclos. so I cannot check

Comment: neither your curl code nor your add_headers function should produce ANY output whatsoever, so there's obviously something you're not telling us. (for example, maybe you have an `echo $response;` following `$response = curl_exec($request);` that you're not showing us?)

Comment: @hanshenrik I have mentioned response `"{"Code":"Validation"}"`

Comment: Can you show what you are doing with `$response`? It is not clear what `"{"Code":"Validation"}"` is coming from. If I copy your code into my IDE, nothing will happen except for the output from curl being assigned to `$response`. But you don't show what you are doing with `$response` that is causing your issue.

Comment: By the way, if the `$response` variable **itself** has double quotes at the start and end, you need to remove them. You can do that with `trim($response, '"')`. Double quotes (or single quotes) are used for assigning string literals to a variable. For example, `$response = "{'foo':'bar'}"`. But after you do that, the contents of `$response` will be `{'foo':'bar'}`. No quotes.

Comment: @KodosJohnson If I put this JSON output `{"amount":"100","description":"A ticket of 100.","payer":null,"successUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/ticket-confirmed.php","successWebhook":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/ticket-confirmed-webhook.php","cancelUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/shop","orderId":"OID-1","expiresAfter":{"amount":1,"field":"hours"},"customValues":{}}` at https://demo.cyclos.org/api#!/Tickets/newTicket then same error comes

Comment: Looks like you need to set a valid payer (`"payer":"valid value"`), despite the doc says it's optional and *should* be left empty. Perhaps you should consult the Cyclos support?

Comment: @Sally CJ when I get remove it errors still have persist. Support not available, posted on forum.cyclos.org

Comment: I was actually referring to contact them directly via email or contact form.. if it's possible? Secondly, I was saying, try using a valid `payer` value - a non-empty user name or ID.

Comment: @SallyCJ I try it using `payer=demo2` but it gives same error: `"{"code":"validation"}"`

Comment: I did suspect it's a user (authorization) issue, but anyway, I'm glad the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turned out to be an issue with the demo account they provide.
The error validation has this description on their documentation site: **Input error. Either a validation error or the maximum allowed items was exceeded**
I created a new account and it is working fine, below is the code that i am using:

```
function add_headers($request) {
    global $config;
    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
    if (true || empty($config['accessClient'])) {
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "geeky:1234");
    } else {
        array_push($headers, "Access-Client-Token: {$config['accessClient']}");
    }
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}

$body = '{"amount":"100","description":"A ticket of 100.","payer":null,"successUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/ticket-confirmed.php","successWebhook":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/ticket-confirmed-webhook.php","cancelUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress5\/shop","orderId":"OID-1","expiresAfter":{"amount":1,"field":"hours"},"customValues":{}}';

$request = curl_init("https://demo.cyclos.org/api/tickets");
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
add_headers($request);    
$response = curl_exec($request);
$response = json_decode($response);
var_dump($response);
```

I have hardcoded the URL and also changed the username to my demo one.
Thank You.

Comment: have you tested it at above Api link

Comment: I have tested the above Code and is returning a long JSON object. You can just copy paste above code in an empty PHP file and run it to see the results.

Comment: it works, can you tell me user configuration required or what issue with user accounts as I have to do it with my own cyclos server

Comment: the default `demo` user they provide has  limitations, so that user can't create many create requests. That is why you were seeing the error. If you have custom installation then this won't be an issue. if you want to use their demo site then register a new user and you still won't experience any issue.

Comment: @SaqibAmin, +1, again.. Sorry, my phone was acting weirdly yesterday. Anyway, it's good to know the actual issue to the problem. Cheers!